# Simulate a network cable unplugged without losing all routes

Tags: linux, networking, iproute

I want to simulate unplugging a cable from a Linux instance. My initial response was `ip link set eth0 down`. However, this command has impact on higher-level networking functions, e.g. routes (including `default` route) are removed, etc. When I "plug it back in" with `ip link set eth0 up`, the routes now are missing.

How can I simulate unplugged network without using `down`, or conversely tell iproute2 to *just* cause the network cable to be disconnected?

Comment: Depends what you want to achieve, exactly. One way might be to filter all packets in and out with `iptables`. Another way might be to disable autonegotiation and configure incompable/mismatched speed and duplex settings on each side of the cable. The latter used to work really well with 10/100 ethernet, I don't know how easy or hard it has become to purposefully break ethernet settings in the era of gige and 10gige...

Comment: Actually, it all is virtual, so playing with auto-negotiation and speeds won't work here. But iptables is a nice idea. I might be able to do something here.

Comment: @Celada iptables was a brilliant idea, and far simpler than anything I had in mind. In my case, I was using containers, so I had to `ip netns exec <pid> iptables ...` but it was excellent. Please propose it as an answer and I will choose it.

Comment: Do you want to simulate unplugging the cable in a way that notifies the OS and applications that the network is down? Or do you want to just temporarily drop all traffic?

Comment: @Giles, I would have preferred the first, which is similar to an actual cable being pulled. However, I could not find any way to do that, without also removing routes and higher level network config, which definitely does *not* happen when a cable is pulled.

Comment: Routes only exist to 'connected' devices - so when a device goes down, the routes are removed. Otherwise those routes would be invalid anyway. There's no way to keep routes up to a downed device without modifying the kernel. But you can use higher-level commands to move routes around, assuming there are routing statements in your network config like the gateway being set. For eg in debian:

`ifdown eth0; sleep 5; ifup eth0`

Comment: routes aren't removed for a device which lost its carrier. They are removed when the device is *administratively* brought down. Of course userland tools like NetworkManager can choose to remove the route when it's notified the carrier is down. But the kernel didn't do it then.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
nmcli device disconnect eth0
```

To turn interface on, use this command.

```
nmcli device connect eth0
```

Note: Please change `eth0` to your interface device.

Comment: Isn't that basically the same as `ip li set down`?